# WPF - Make a TextBlock expand to fit text but not exceed available space?

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPF veteran here who can't seem to figure out what should be a simple problem:

I want to lay out two controls horizontally such that the first expands only as wide as necessary to fit its contents, but no more than its available space. Specifically I want to be able to make the first control a `TextBlock` with text wrapping, but I don't want short text labels to have huge whitespace before the second item. (The second box is an (i) glyph with a tooltip, FYI).

Visually this is what I want:

[image]

My first thought was to use a `Grid` with two columns, `Auto` and `*`. But this causes the text never to wrap, presumably because its `MeasureOverride` is being told its available width is infinity. `* Auto`, of course, forces the blue box to the right no matter how short the text is.

I thought maybe I could make the first column `Width="Auto" MaxWidth="*"` but `MaxWidth` is a straight `double` and doesn't allow star notation.

Also tried `DockPanel`, making the `TextBlock` undocked. This almost works but as the container is resized the blue box is cut off and replaced with "..." (I'm not a big user of `DockPanel` so it's possible I'm doing something wrong).

I finally tried naming the first column and binding the `TextBlock`'s `Width` to the `ActualWidth` of the column, but this completely messed up the layout.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful, if you share your xaml code

Comment: I didn't see the point since my XAML code doesn't get what I want but I will see if I can put together a minimalist example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `DockPanel` seems to work, when you set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="16" Height="16" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <TextBlock Text="Short" Background="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="16" Height="16" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <TextBlock Text="Long test that should wrap when it fills available space" Background="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Putting the `Rectangle` first in the XAML order and setting `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` will solve the issue of the rectangle being cut off when resizing.

Comment: Unfortunately no, when you shrink the window the blue box starts to get cut off until the text block shrinks enough that another word gets pushed onto the next line.

Comment: Fixed. Just needed to put the Rectangle first in the XAML order and set DockingPanel.Dock="Right".

Comment: Well how about that? That did it! But I have confess I don't understand why that works but putting the TextBlock in a grid with auto column width doesn't. It seems to me the Grid should not be giving Infinity as the available width to MeasureOverride, but that sure seems like what's happening. The DockPanel behaves more sensibly. Well anyway your XAML-only solution works so you get the answer mark from me. Cheers!

Comment: Also should note aligning the DockPanel Left is key as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still be interested in knowing if there is a XAML-only solution, but here's what I wound up doing:

```
public class SmartStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    #region bool AutoStretch dependency property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoStretchProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AutoStretch", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(SmartStackPanel));
    public static bool GetAutoStretch(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(AutoStretchProperty);
    }
    public static void SetAutoStretch(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(AutoStretchProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        if (double.IsInfinity(constraint.Width) && this.Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal ||
            double.IsInfinity(constraint.Height) && this.Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical)
            return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        
        int c = this.VisualChildrenCount;

        Size final = default;

        double remaining = 0;
        List<UIElement> autoChildren = new List<UIElement>();

        if (this.Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            remaining = constraint.Width;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                var child = this.GetVisualChild(i) as UIElement;
                if (child == null)
                    continue;

                bool autoStretch = GetAutoStretch(child);
                if (!autoStretch)
                {
                    child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, constraint.Height));
                    remaining -= child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    final.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    final.Height = Math.Max(final.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    autoChildren.Add(child);
                }               
            }

            if (remaining > 0 && autoChildren.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var autoChild in autoChildren)
                {
                    autoChild.Measure(new Size(remaining / autoChildren.Count, constraint.Height));
                    final.Height = Math.Max(final.Height, autoChild.DesiredSize.Height);
                }
                final.Width += remaining;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        return final;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        <local:SmartStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Long text that should wrap when it fills available space" 
                       Background="Red" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       local:SmartStackPanel.AutoStretch="True"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="16" Height="16" />
        </local:SmartStackPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but can't you just use a WrapPanel? If you wanted to do something fancy with the width of the wrapped TextBlock next to it, you could do some binding also:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanel1">
    <TextBlock>Short</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=wrapPanel1}">
        Long text that should wrap when it flls available
        space.dfsfdsfs fsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfssfsfsd
    </TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

Here I've just linked the width to the parent WrapPanel, but you could have a width calculated using a custom dependency property as well.